# How to properly set a timer for a function that positions your elements based in a formula?

Tags: javascript, html, timer, positioning

I have a function that positions elements of my page. For example:

```
refresh_positions = function(){
    set_pos(arrow_div,mouse_x,mouse_y);
    set_pos(title_tiv,window_width/2,20);
};
```

This, obviously, must run continously, as fast as possible, in order for the elements to always be positioned correctly. But how?

If I set a fast timer like `setInterval(refresh_positions,10)`, slower computers will freeze. If I set a slower timer, faster computers will have a worse experience. I also have a concern with battery drainage in mobile devices. What's the right way of positioning elements based on a function?

Comment: What is the user scenario that fires the refresh_points function? Mousemove, window resize, hover on an element?

Comment: It could be anything, some elements are just positioned in function of time (sine waves) so I couldn't really filter for some events like onmousemove (if that's what you're suggesting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `setTimeout` or `window.requestAnimationFrame`, this ensures that new function call will only be queued when the previous function finished to run. In this way the Browser UI wont freeze that fast if the function takes longer than the interval you planned for.

```
var interval = <so many seconds should it take>;

function update(){
    //do you stuff here




    setTimeout( update, interval );
    //or
    window.requestAnimationFrame( update );
}
```

the second approach with `window.requestAnimationFrame` has the advantage that the is triggered up to sixty times a second if possible, or less if the browser cannot run it that fast. Also the callback is not triggered if the tab or the browser looses focus.

Comment: Just for additional knowledge, window.requestAnimationFrame is *already* triggered for some build-in functions 60 times a second anyway, right? That is, can I not worry and simply add that small "refresh_positions" function to **all** my pages, or should I actually worry in only enabling it when necessary (which will complicate the usage of the API itself)?

Comment: I do not clearly get what you mean with »not worry to put it on all pages«, but if you are talking about multiple tabs and windows opened at the same time showing your website, than `window.requestAnimationFrame` will trigger only the callback on the active page with focus. All in all the performance just depends on what you are doing inside the loop, too much will be slow on one or on multiple pages.

Comment: No, I'm asking if it's fine to make my library automatically start the refresh_positions continuous call when it is loaded. That is, refresh_positions would be running even if a user of the library wasn't actually using dynamic positions. If running refresh_positions continously makes no difference in performance, then that's fine. If not, I'd better make users who want the dynamic positioning behaviors to actively call "enableDynamicPositioning()" or something similar. So, again: is that function I posted lightweight enough to be always running on requestAnimFrames without worries?

Comment: since you gave no code for `set_pos(arrow_div,mouse_x,mouse_y);` and `set_pos(title_tiv,window_width/2,20);` no one can tell because it depends on what you are doing there. I personally think that libs or frameworks should not start timers from out of the box, because I want to control it and probably trigger the update myself together with other stuff, but that is my point of view.